# Round robin a list in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a method which behaves as a round robin. Everytime someone calls it, it returns an integer from a list. When the end of the list is reached, it starts serving from the beginning.

I call this method from a stateless session bean.

The method is written in a util class like below

```
public final class MyUtil {

    private static int index;

    private MyUtil() {}

    public synchronized static int getNextInt() {
        Properties p = DBconfigModule.getProperties("key");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(((String) p.get("key")).split(","));
        try {
        if(index>=list.size()) {
           index = 0;
           next = list.get(0);
           index++;
        } else {
           next = list.get(index):
           index++;
        }
        } catch(final Exception e) {
             // log
             index = 0;
             next = list.get(0);
             index++;
        }
    return Integer.parseInt(next);
}

@Stateless
public class Usage {
    public int getNextInt() {
        return MyUtil.getNextInt();
    }
}
```

I am not sure how far what i have written is right and will work.

Can anyone tell me is this right and suggest me if it can be improved?

I do not want to use any 3pp libraries for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a problem/question? If you're asking for code review you might want to look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am asking for review. Thanks i will post it there

Comment: Re, "I am not sure [that] what i have written [...] will work."  So test it, right?

Comment: One thing bothers me slightly, It's your comment, `get the list from cache.`  That makes me wonder whether the list could ever change, and that makes me wonder whether the list could ever _shrink_.  What would happen if `index` ever was greater than `list.size()` (e.g., because the list shrank)?

Comment: @james: yes the list will grow and shrink occasionally. Now I have another check in my code. If index is greater than list.size then I will again reset the index to 0. We actually cache table entries. So when there is a change in table the cache will be updated. This is when the list grows of shrinks

Comment: The check on list.size() does not help you. The thread reading the list (the code you showed us) might not be aware of your list beeing changed from some other Thread.

Comment: I would use ReadWriteLock to guard the access to the list. This way multiple unblocking reads are possible and only the occasional write (list changed) would block the readers. Second, I would use AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet % list.size() to get the current index. For this you would need to lock the list for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct only if `list` is never changed or if access to list is `synchronized` with the same monitor.

Imagine what happens when the following code is executed:

```
Thread 1                           Thread 2
-------------------                -----------------------
// index = 2
// list.size() = 3
if (index == list.size()) {

                                    // Removes first element
                                    // now list.size() = 2
                                    list.remove(0);


} else {
   // Will throw an exception
   // Because now list has size 2
   // and the third element (index 2) 
   // doesn't exists
   next = list.get(index);
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for pointing the bug. As you mentioned, the list is going to change occasionally. Will adding a check on the index against the size like `if(index>list.size()) then index =0` help me solve this problem?

Comment: It is possible to surround the code modifying the list with a synchronized block using the same monitor

Comment: no it is not possible because the list is modified somewhere else. We load the list from a cache which listens to a database table change. When there are changes in table the cache will be refreshed. That is the reason, I am loading the list always from the cache

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger; 
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;


public class Counter {

    private ReadWriteLock listLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private AtomicInteger indexCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    Integer getNextInt() {
        Lock readLock = listLock.readLock();
        try {
            if(list==null || list.size() == 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Call setList() with  some values first.");
             }
             int index = indexCounter.incrementAndGet() % list.size();
             return list.get(index);
        } finally {
             readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void setList(List<Integer> newList) {
        Lock writeLock = listLock.writeLock();
        try {
            this.list = newList;
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that, very roughly.

Comment: thanks for pointing the bug. The code which populates the list is a legacy code. I dont think i can change it. Meanwhile i added a try catch in my code. I will try to influence the original developers to add the lock on the legacy code. Thank you.